# Cookies not being set in client-side for MERN Auth App using JWT after deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, mern, render.com

I have developed a MERN authentication application where I'm using JWT to authorize users. The server is hosted at [api.somanyu.tech](https://api.somanyu.tech), and the client is hosted at [finapp.somanyu.tech](https://finapp.somanyu.tech). Both server and client are deployed at [Render](https://render.com/) and hosted with [get.tech](https://get.tech/)

The problem I'm facing is the cookies are not getting set on the client-side. When I inspect the cookies in the browser, only Cloudflare's cookies (`__cf_bm`, `_cfuvid`) are showing up, but not the token cookie which I want to set.

In `authController.js` I am generating the token and setting the cookie as below.

```js
// Generate JWT Token.
const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
  expiresIn: "36h",
});

console.log("GENERATED TOKEN\n", token);

if (req.cookies[`${user._id}`]) {
  req.cookies[`${user._id}`] = "";
}

// Set cookie.
res.cookie(String(user._id), token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  path: '/*',
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + 100 * 30),
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
  sameSite: 'none',
  domain: 'finapp.somanyu.tech',
  secure: true,
});

return res.status(201).send({ success: "Signed in successfully." });
```

And also create a middleware `authMiddleware.js` to verify token every time a user goes to '/user' route.

```js
const verifyToken = async (req, res, next) => {

    // Retrieve cookies from header.
    const cookies = req.headers.cookie;
    console.log(" ~ file: authMiddleware.js:7 ~ verifyToken ~ cookies:", cookies)
    if (cookies) {
        const cookie = cookies.split("=")[1];
        const token = jwt.verify(cookie, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (error, user) => {
            if (error) return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid Token" });
            req.user = user._id; // Id of the user who is logged in.
            next();
        });
    } else {
        return res.status(401).json({ error: "No Token" });
    }
}
```

Everything was working perfectly in my localhost but once I deployed it whole the cookies stopped getting stored in browser. The `verifyToken()` middleware basically read the cookies in header and then verify the JWT token and return user data to the requested routes.
I have consoled log the token and the token is getting generated and when I access the `req.headers.cookies` and console log it there is only Cloudflare's cookies (`__cf_bm`, `_cfuvid`).

I guess I might be missing out some important steps but this is my first time hosting a MERN app.

The GitHub repos - 
Client - https://github.com/Somanyu/server-finproject 
Server - https://github.com/Somanyu/client-finproject

Answer (score 0):

Try to see console.log(req.headers) what it contains.
And also some notes for don’t declare a function inside the attribute call it before the return, and for the Toastcontainer you can call it in the App.js which wrap all the components, and give it the details you want and in the other files you can use toast and its type and the message without recurring the details for the notification.

Comment: I did the console log for the `req.headers` but as I said in the question only thing that logs out is the Cloudflare's cookies (`__cf_bm`,  `_cfuvid`).

Comment: try res.headers instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).